# How to implement a pullable layout

Tags: android, layout, android-gesture, android-motionlayout

I want to implement a layout and animation in such a way that when we try to pull down a layout it should increase its height and expand to downwards and its edge should be round. and same way to pull up. It should increase its height and move upwards and its edge should be round. I don't know how to start and where to start.

> What I tried till now.
>
> I tried to implement library
>   https://github.com/marcorighini/PullableView but, it shows me error
>   while building the project:
>
> Failed to resolve: com.github.marcorighini:PullableView:1.1.0
>
> I also opened an issue in GitHub.
>   https://github.com/marcorighini/PullableView/issues/3
>
> There is a demo too, for that layout.  that how a layout should be
>   pulled down
>   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yN2OHmYrpMZ0Uh7oo3N6HXd_x2dREK44

What I want to achieve is shown in the image

[image]

can anybody help me? It would be good if anyone can provide any information regarding this problem to start with. And if there is a library for it then that would be great. thanks in advance. Please help me.

Comment: Have you downloaded demo?

Comment: Does this not look like a common ScrollView?

Comment: @Khemraj no, its not like a scrollview

Comment: Instead of using dependency use library project. That will be worked. It has a classes which can be accessible.

Comment: You can achieve this with BottomSheetFragmentDialog / BottomSheetBehaviour too. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior & https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: @Khemraj  can I do with both the directions? (i.e. bottom and top).

Comment: Collapsing toolbar can also be useful for jumping animations. https://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN820IN821&biw=1920&bih=938&ei=ZV3-W8vUMpyUvQSMk4qAAQ&q=collapsing+toolbar+android+github&oq=collapsing+toolbar+android+github&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i7i30l6j0i5i30j0i8i30l2.25753.25753..26007...0.0..0.143.143.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.9mQrNsYSl40

Comment: @Riddhi Is your issue solved?

Comment: @Piyush No. I am still searching the easy and the best way to do it. Though above suggestions are really good, and i will try them too one by one.

Comment: @Riddhi Okay So the demo project not working then can you share the link for it? Because I want to try it

Comment: @Riddhi Drive link is demo implemented by you?

Comment: @Piyush. No, I was trying to do so, but the library was throwing some error. So i Could not.

Comment: @Piyush right now, I have just performed swipe up and swipe down detection

Comment: @Riddhi You done it ??

Comment: @Piyush no, not yet.

Comment: @Riddhi I am able to run the app and it's working from down to up pull. Do you need both or single?

Comment: @Piyush I need both side